Native federation - Angular 17: Not Found http://localhost:4201/_angular_core-17_0_5-dev.js
I am working with micro frontends using native federation in Angular 17. And when I run the microfront and my host app, and I load my host app in the browser, I get the folloging error, and I don't know why.
_angular_core-17_3_12-dev.js:3806 ERROR TypeError: 404 Not Found http://localhost:4201/_angular_core-17_0_5-dev.js imported from http://localhost:4201/routes.js
    at doFetch (es-module-shims.js:816:21)
    at async fetchModule (es-module-shims.js:825:17)
    at async es-module-shims.js:895:40
handleError @ _angular_core-17_3_12-dev.js:3806Understand this error
:4201/ngx_highlightjs-10_0_0-dev.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)Understand this error
:4201/_angular_router-17_0_5-dev.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)Understand this error
zone.js:1777 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 16907ms

And in the microfrontend console I get the folloging warning and errors:
_angular_core-17_3_12-dev.js:3806 ERROR TypeError: 404 Not Found http://localhost:4201/_angular_core-17_0_5-dev.js imported from http://localhost:4201/routes.js
    at doFetch (es-module-shims.js:816:21)
    at async fetchModule (es-module-shims.js:825:17)
    at async es-module-shims.js:895:40
handleError @ _angular_core-17_3_12-dev.js:3806Understand this error
:4201/ngx_highlightjs-10_0_0-dev.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)Understand this error
:4201/_angular_router-17_0_5-dev.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)Understand this error
zone.js:1777 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 16907ms```


Jesus Sanchez, did you find the solution?
